# Access content inside collapsible div from another page

Tags: jquery, html, hash, anchor

I have two HTML Files. This is File No. 1.

```
      <p class="Heading">
              <a name="car"></a>Small vehicles</p>
      <! -- BEGIN COLLAPSIBLE CONTENT >
      <div class="description">
                    CONTENT
      </div>
      <END COLLAPSIBLE CONTENT>  
      <p class="Heading">
            <a name="truck"></a>Big vehicles</p>
       <div class="description">
       <! -- BEGIN COLLAPSIBLE CONTENT >
                      CONTENT 
       </div>
       <END COLLAPSIBLE CONTENT>
```

HTML File No. 2 has a link for Small Vehicles to be accessed in File No. 1. 
When I click on the link in File No. 2, I need it to show the collapsible content inside Small vehicles heading.

For example,  (page.html#car")

Javascript function:

```
   $(document).ready(function() { 

   $(".Heading").click(function()  {  

       $(this).next(".description").slideToggle(500);  });

    });
```

I have used the anchor name in File No. 1 and Used hash tag in File No. 2 to access that content.

The problem I am having is that I am able to get to that page (page.html) but it is not showing the content inside the collapsible div Small Vehicles.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you give car and truck anchors an id, not just a name, you could do the following check in document.ready:

```
if(window.location.hash && window.location.hash.replace("#", "") == "car"){
    $("#car").parent(".Heading").trigger("click");
}
```

This will simulate a click on the car heading and expand the content.

I would also look into reconsidering the structure of your html - why not make the links something like `<a id="car" class="Header">Small vehicles</a>` and forget the `<p>` ?  This may simplify things and make it easier to work with.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Here is a jfiddle for File No. 1. (http://jsfiddle.net/y8T84/1/). Do I need to put this code right in the document.ready function?

Comment: I made some edits to be more like I intended.  The trigger would go inside a check.  You want to trigger it if the page is loaded with the #car hashtag.  jsfiddle.net/y8T84/6/

Comment: I tried what you had suggested but it just goes to the page. It does not open the DIV. I updated the jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/y8T84/8/). I added ( $('.description').show();) to test if it opens the hash tag. It goes to the #car but opens up all the DIV's.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Code works for:**  External Page Link to expand Collapse DIV on another page BUT will NOT hide the window.location.hash when clicking on
   other collapse buttons on same page:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $(window.location.hash).show();
   });
   ```

   2. **Code works for:** External Page Link to expand Collapse DIV on another page AND will hide the window.location.hash when clicking on other
      collapse buttons. Collapse function of other buttons work correctly:

      $(document).ready(function() {
         $(window.location.hash).addClass('collapse in');
         });